# boost async ws server checking client information

Tags: c++, boost, websocket, boost-beast, boost-beast-websocket

How do i check client information as user-agent from boost async web socket server ?

I have checked:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/websocket/server/async/websocket_server_async.cpp

It was my only referance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `async_accept` on the websocket here:

```
    // Accept the websocket handshake
    ws_.async_accept(
        beast::bind_front_handler(
            &session::on_accept,
            shared_from_this()));
```

You could read a HTTP request instead and call the [third overload](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream/async_accept.html) instead:

```
    // read upgrade request
    http::async_read(ws_.next_layer(), buffer_, upgrade_request_,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &session::on_upgrade,
                shared_from_this()));
```

And then outside `on_run()`:

```
http::request<http::string_body> upgrade_request_;

void
on_upgrade(beast::error_code ec, size_t) {
    if(ec)
        return fail(ec, "upgrade");
    // Accept the websocket handshake
    ws_.async_accept(
        upgrade_request_,
        beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_accept, shared_from_this()));
}
```

This gives you the opportunity to do stuff inside `on_upgrade` that inspects the upgrade request:

```
void
on_upgrade(beast::error_code ec, size_t) {
    if(ec)
        return fail(ec, "upgrade");

    std::cout << "Upgrade request user-agent: " << upgrade_request_[http::field::user_agent] << "\n";
    std::cout << "Upgrade request headers: " << upgrade_request_.base() << "\n";
    std::cout << "Upgrade request body: " << upgrade_request_.body() << "\n";

    // Accept the websocket handshake
    ws_.async_accept(
        upgrade_request_,
        beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_accept, shared_from_this()));
}
```

Indeed using wscat as client:

```
wscat -c "ws://localhost:9797/" -H 'User-agent: Slartibartfast'
```

Causes our Beast server to print out:

```
Upgrade request user-agent: Slartibartfast
Upgrade request headers: GET / HTTP/1.1
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: o6j5v6YeqI4vEJT6AiVTyA==
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
User-agent: Slartibartfast
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Host: localhost:9797


Upgrade request body:
```

Comment: I was getting buffer overflow using wss in async_accept, I tried this code and it seems to fix the issue. But now I am seeing a lot of crash. Any idea why that can be? @sehe

Comment: @ksohan Yeah. The code is probably broken. If you want help you should show your self-contained code in a question