# How to print the WebSocket HTTP Upgrade Request?

Tags: boost, boost-beast-websocket

Reference: [websocket_client_sync.cpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/sync/websocket_client_sync.cpp)

```
Table 1.30. WebSocket HTTP Upgrade Request

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 2pGeTR0DsE4dfZs2pH+8MA==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Boost.Beast/216
```

**Question**> Based on the example `websocket_client_sync.cpp`, which function is used to send a HTTP Upgrade Request similar as the one shown above and how can I print the request shown above?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a duplicate, but I can't mark it as such because this answer was never accepted¹:

[boost async ws server checking client information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71212992/boost-async-ws-server-checking-client-information#71246212)

In short use the overload of accept that that takes a request object that you have previously read.

The linked answer has a complete live demo.

---

¹ answering on Stack overflow can be pretty thankless at times

### UPDATE

To the comment, I apologize for missing the client/server distinction initially. The client has a similar overload on `handshake` that allows you to inspect the upgrade *response*:

```
http::response<http::string_body> res;
ws.handshake(res, host, "/");
std::cout << res;
```

Printing e.g.

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: /wp5bsjYquNsAIhi4lKoIuDm0TY=
```

However, the request is not directly exposed. I suppose it's best monitored with a network packet sniffer or from the server side. If the goal is to **manipulate** the upgrade request, you should use a `RequestDecorator`.

PS: I just checked and the request decorator [is applied nearly-at-the-end](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/boost/beast/websocket/impl/stream_impl.hpp#:%7E:text=decorator(req)) (although some things related to per-message-deflate might be added on later in the `handshake_op`). So you might be content with just supplying a decorator that inspects the request:

```
http::response<http::string_body> res;
ws.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
    [](http::request<http::empty_body>& req) {
        std::cout << "--- Upgrade request: " << req << std::endl;
    }));
ws.handshake(res, host, "/");
std::cout << "--- Upgrade response: " << res << std::endl;
```

Which prints e.g.

```
--- Upgrade request: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:10000
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: Quyn+IEvycAhcRtlvPIS4A==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13


--- Upgrade response: HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: aRDrnkHhNfaPqGdsisX51rjj+fI=
```

Comment: I might misunderstood the concept, but the example is from a client side. I assume the `accept` call is on the server side. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: Oh yeah. I missed that. Updated the answer. Sadly it's not straightforward to access the request.

Comment: PS. You can probably inspect the request from a (no-op) decorator, come to think of it: [`build_request` calls the decorator last](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/boost/beast/websocket/impl/stream_impl.hpp#:~:text=decorator(req)). Also updated the answer